# Failing to capture stdout from application

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following script:

```
import subprocess

arguments = ["d:\\simulator","2332.txt","2332.log", "-c"]

output=subprocess.Popen(arguments, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
print(output)
```

which gives me b'' as output.

I also tried this script:

```
import subprocess

arguments = ["d:\\simulator","2332.txt","atp2332.log", "-c"]
process = subprocess.Popen(arguments,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()

print(process.stdout.read())
print("ERROR:" + str(process.stderr))
```

which gives me the output: b'', ERROR:None

However when I run this at the cmd prompt I get a 5 lines of text.

> d:\simulator atp2332.txt atp2332.log -c

I have added to simulator a message box which pops up when it launches. This is presented for all three cases. So I know that I sucessfully launch the simulator. However the python scripts are not caturing the stdout.

What am I doing wrong?

Barry.

Comment: Why do you have `process.stdout.read()` on one line and `str(process.stderr)` on the next, in your second code sample? Shouldn't you use `read()` in both cases?

Comment: Yes, your right. When I try:<pre>process = subprocess.Popen(arguments,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)</pre> I get an empty string for stderr also.

Answer (score 2):

If possible (not endless stream of data) you should use [communicate()](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) as noted on the page.

Try this:

```
import subprocess

arguments = ["d:\\simulator","2332.txt","atp2332.log", "-c"]
process = subprocess.Popen(arguments, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
sout, serr = process.communicate()

print(sout)
print(serr)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code gives me text output on stdout.
Perhaps you could try it, and then substitute your command for help

```
import subprocess

arguments = ["help","2332.txt","atp2332.log", "-c"]
process = subprocess.Popen(arguments,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()

print 'Return code', process.returncode
print('stdout:', process.stdout.read())
print("stderr:" + process.stderr.read())
```